# How to write a scripted field to get the number of days between status transition

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I have two fields in an index named created_on and closed_on with date format July 15th 2019, 17:40:09.000, i want to write a painless scripted field to calculate the number of days between these two dates.

I have tried this:

```
def res_date= 0; 
def closing_date = 0;
if ( doc['status_id'].value == 51 ) {
res_date = doc['e_created_date'].date.getMillis();
}
if ( doc['status_id'].value == 20 ) {
closing_date = doc['closed_on'].date.getMillis();
}
def day = 0;
day= (closing_date - res_date) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);  
return day;
```

I'm getting wrong day value.

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL3dp.png)

Comment: Does each document have a single value for `status_id`? if that's the case, you'll always end up with only one date (either `res_date` or `closing_date`) in the context of each document. Hence your computation cannot succeed. Also I don't see any `closed_on` field in your script.

Comment: Yes each document has a single value for `status_id`. I have edited the script now with `closed_on` field

Comment: ok, but you have to know that script fields execute in the context **of a single document**, so there's no way you can compute what you expect that way (i.e. with script fields). Maybe show some sample data and what you expect out of them

Comment: I have added an image which contains the sample data

Comment: Ok, so you need to aggregate by `issue_id` and then find the number of days between the time the issue was opened (status 20) and when it was closed (status 51). Is that it?

Comment: Yes, correct, you have summed it up perfectly

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to aggregate by `issue_id` and then find the number of days between the time the issue was opened (status 20) and when it was closed (status 51).

You should be able to run the query below and find exactly what you need in the `diff_days` bucket field in the response:

```
GET test2/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "issues": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "issue_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "openedStatus": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "status_id": "51"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "openedDate": {
              "min": {
                "field": "created_on"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "closedStatus": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "status_id": "20"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "closedDate": {
              "min": {
                "field": "closed_on"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "diff_days": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "opened": "openedStatus>openedDate",
              "closed": "closedStatus>closedDate"
            },
            "script": "(params.closed - params.opened) / 86400000"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results =>

```
"issues" : {
  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
  "buckets" : [
    {
      "key" : 167893,
      "doc_count" : 3,
      "closedStatus" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "closedDate" : {
          "value" : 1.565005134E12,
          "value_as_string" : "2019-08-05T11:38:54.000Z"
        }
      },
      "openedStatus" : {
        "doc_count" : 2,
        "openedDate" : {
          "value" : 1.559556432E12,
          "value_as_string" : "2019-06-03T10:07:12.000Z"
        }
      },
      "diff_days" : {
        "value" : 63.06368055555556                     <--- 63 days
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I ran the query, it returned an error `illegal_argument_exception` the reason was `Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default.`. I changed the query from `issue_id` to `issue_id.keyword` it ran without errors but did not get the desired output.

Comment: What did you get instead?

Comment: `root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [issue_id] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
      }
    ]`

Comment: Can you try `issue_id.keyword` instead?